# How to recover gitlab wiki from backup

Tags: gitlab, mingw

We have damaged server, where our gitlab was running. Also we have had a backup, which is stored locally now. However, it turns out, that backup has had some damaged files, so we are not able to recover from it. There is no problem with repo, however gitlab's wiki contains a lot of useful information. I've already run `printf "%s\n" "$src/@hashed"/*/*/* | grep '\.wiki\.git$'` and found out, that backup contains a lot of hashed files with our wiki. Is there a way to translate them or move to our new empty gitlab?

Answer (score 0):

> backup contains a lot of hashed files with our wiki. Is there a way to translate them or move to our new empty gitlab?

Yes, see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/repository_storage_types.html#from-hashed-path-to-project-name about the name/path hashing.

[Alternatively](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/troubleshooting/linux_cheat_sheet.html#file-contents), if the wiki's companion project is not damaged, you can run `grep 'fullpath' config` in its `@hashed/…/…not…wiki….git` folder.

Either way, it should be possible to `git clone` the `.bundle` files, thus generating a normal repo from them, which you can push again to a new wiki, or extract the file content from.

Comment: .bundle local folder seems to be empty. 
Alternatively, if the wiki's companion project is not damaged, you can run grep 'fullpath' config in its @hashed/…/…not…wiki….git folder - ok, with grep I would get non wiki paths (if i understand right your approach). But git wiki config files do not contain fullpaths. What should I do with this?

Comment: `fullpath` of a wiki should be the same as its companion project, and the `@hashed/…/….git` path as well.